# WordPress Sage Custom Post Type template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have made a Custom Post Type with the name `product`.
Now my goals is to use a template file for all product that I will add.

I am using Sage for developing my theme.

So far I have created in the root of my theme a file named `single-product.php` that looks like this:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/product-single', get_post_type()); ?>
```

My `templates/product-single` looks like this:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1>hey</h1>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So in theory I should see `hey` when I go to a products page. Unfortunately I get this error:

> Not Found Sorry,
>
> but the page you were trying to view does not exist.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I had to flush my rewrite settings. A quick way to do this is, is to save your permalinks settings.